# jQuery hide() works, but show() does not

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having trouble getting this script to work.

```
  <asp:DropDownList CssClass="workUnit" Width=80 ID="dropdownWorkUnit" runat="server" Visible="false" _clientId="comboboxWorkUnit" />
```

For some reason, the combobox will not become visible when I run this JavaScript.

```
onPhaseChange: function(dropdown, row) {
    var combobox = $(dropdown);
    comboboxWorkUnit = row.find("select.workUnit");
    comboboxWorkUnit.show();
},
```

But when I do this, it works:

```
onPhaseChange: function(dropdown, row) {
    var combobox = $(dropdown);
    comboboxWorkUnit = row.find("select.workUnit");
    comboboxWorkUnit.hide();
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that if you set a server side control visible=FALSE it will not render the control html in the page, and so jQuery will not find it.

Comment: interesting so i would have to hide the dropdown when the page loads?

Comment: I don't know about the ASP code, but you can add style="display:none" as an HTML attribute.  This way it's hidden by default, but you can show/hide it as needed.

Comment: when i tryed style="display:none"  it still was visible for some reason